# Flutter Bloc Pattern - Create a class that creates class events

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Simplifying my own scenario for the sake of this Q&A...

Hypothetical Scenario: In a todo app, the todo object is comprised of 100 properties. A form has 100 `TextField`s to create/edit the todo object.

The app uses the flutter_bloc package. For each of the 100 properties there is a corresponding bloc event triggered when the user interacts with the `TextField`.

```
part of 'edit_entry_bloc.dart';

abstract class EditEntryEvent extends Equatable {
  const EditEntryEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

// This class is number #1 of 100 to extend the abstract class. 
// 99 similar classes will follow.
class EditEntryTitleChanged extends EditEntryEvent {
  const EditEntryTitleChanged(this.title);

  final String title;

  @override 
  List<Object> get props => [title];
}
```

Instead of repeating that code 99 more times, how would one create a factory (unsure of the correct terminology / solution / method) to essentially create:

```
class EditEntry${oneStringVariable}Changed extends EditEntryEvent {
  const EditEntry${oneStringVariable}Changed(this.${oneStringVariable});

  final String ${oneStringVariable};

  @override 
  List<Object> get props => [${oneStringVariable}];
}
```

And how would that be used in the `TextField` where the common implementation is:

```
onChanged: (value) {
        context.read<EditEntryBloc>().add(EditEntryTitleChanged(value));
```

Edit: I originally used the word "generate" instead of "factory". I realize now that "generate" could be construed to mean I actually want to create that many lines of code in the file (similar to json_serializable). I do not. "Factory" may not be technically correct either. The solution I envision would look something like this in the edit_entry_bloc.dart file:

```
...
on<NewSolution>(_newSolutionMethod);
}

void _onNewSolutionMethod(
    EditEntryTitleChanged event,
    Emitter<EditEntryState> emit,
    String string,
) {
emit(state.copywith(${string}: event.${string})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to store your textEditionControllers inside your stateful widget and assign them to your textfiles. when the user clicks submit. AddEvent class which receives 100 properties emits and updates state.

something like this:

```dart
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  TextEditingController controller1 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller2 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller3 = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: controller1,
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: controller2,
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: controller3,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<EditEntryBloc>().add(AddEvent(
                  controller1.value, controller2.value, controller3.value));
            },
            child: Text("submit")),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

remember using state management doesn't mean you don't have to use the stateful widget. something like controller and some UI states should be stored in a stateful widget. it leads to cleaner code and even better performance.

Comment: Fair point for that hypothetical situation. Still, I'm curious to know what the solution is for the posed question. I'd like to expand my tool bag of options for different scenarios.